# How to get defined Tax rate percent prgramatically?

Tags: tax, sales

We have created tax rates in 
`sales->Taxes->Zone&Rates` with `Rate Percent` of xx.xx,
Can we fetch this fetch this details programmatically before placing order for using it API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$rateCollection = Mage::getModel('tax/calculation_rate')->getCollection()
            ->joinRegionTable();
//echo '<pre>';         
 foreach($rateCollection as $rate) {
     echo 'Country => '.$rate->getTaxCountryId().' Rate Percent => '.$rate->getRate();
     echo '<br>';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @Abdul,

I also found this another solution ,

```
$customer_tax_class = '5';
        $rates = $tax->load($customer_tax_class, 'customer_tax_class_id');
        $request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest()->setProductClassId(2)->setCustomerClassId(5);
        echo $percent = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($request);
```